# Flutter implement silver search bar inside cupertino bar?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I want something effect like this:

[image]

As you know, this is a very common usage in iOS, but I don't know how to implement it inside flutter.

I am using CupertinoNavBar inside a silver list, but I can not make a SearchBar like this and collapse while scroll up.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @MobileMon No, I dont know how to do that yet